# How do I exit eagle vision in Assassin's Creed 2?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2

I am just starting out in Assassin's Creed 2, trying to associate a given action with the button it is bound to.  I find myself continually pressing the button for Eagle Vision, and I can't seem to exit this mode until I find an actionable item and activate it.  How do I exit Eagle Vision mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the PC version is like the 360 version, you hold the button you used to activate Eagle Vision for around 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Yes, pressing and *holding* works!  Thank you.  Only had to hold for about a second though.

Comment: I'm not the best judge of time, edited.

Comment: omg, thank you very much. Controls in AC2 is so awful

Comment: As a PC player of Assassin's Creed II, I Can say that pressing and hold ( for 2 ~ 3 secs) keyboard key "E" exists or activate the Eagle Vision